# Unable to assign a pointer to character to array of chararacters

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I need to assign a pointer to an array of characters:

```
char str1[17];
char* h="hey";
str1 = h;
```

But i get this error : `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char [17]'`.

I was thinking that an array name is the same as a pointer to a character and array name is the address of the first character of the array so assigning a pointer to a char to array name would work.

I don't know why i get the error.

How can i fix it?

Comment: if you can not fix this. *str1* is constant pointer. it can not be changed. you can copy "hey" to *str1* but not change *str1*

Comment: There is nothing about Win32 in this question so edited to remove the winapi tag and mention of the Win32 API.

Comment: Use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make `str1` point to a different address.

What you can do is use `strncpy` to copy *the contents* of `h` into `str1`.